# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Invalid data, chunk must be a string or buffer, not object

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3

I recently changed my OS from Windows to Linux and I am running my ionic 3 project by ionic cordova run android and getting this error. It is running well on Windows but giving problem on Linux.

This is not duplicate,because I searched alot and didnt found any solution.

Please somebody help me
Thanks in advance.

Comment: delete your node_modules folder, remove both platforms, android and ios and add again, also install all modules

Comment: I removed platforms and I added them again,secondly I updated by cordova plugin also

Comment: have you removed all installed plugins and reinstalled them?

Comment: Yes as you suggested i did the same but same error continues..

Comment: are you using push notification plugin?

Comment: Yes I am using fcm plugin,

Comment: remove `google-services.json` file, open the firebase project settings and re-download the file and make sure it has API Key

Comment: Nitin i have already done that but no positive result, i have removed fcm plugin and reinstalled it but the error is same

Comment: I removed some unwanted plugins now getting this error: "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory."

Answer (score 0):

I removed platforms and I added them again,secondly I updated my Cordova plugin also,After that I have installed jdk8 and set the path and now it is running fine.

@Nitin P
Thank you  for your support.